# Grails - display date by taking into account Time Zone's user

Tags: grails, timezone

I know I have to set the TimeZone somewhere but I don't know how can I "get" the current TimeZone from the user and display (dynamically?) the date with the correct offset.

This is my code:

Domain:

```
class MyClass {

  Date myDate

}
```

Controller:

```
def unixSeconds = 1386760029
Date date = new Date(unixSeconds*1000L)
```

GSP:

```
<g:formatDate format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" date="${MyClassInstance.myDate}" timeZone="${TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have the user timezone because this information is not sent in the request.

You could try to get the user location using [Geolocation](http://grails.org/plugin/geolocation) or [GeoIP](http://grails.org/plugin/geoip) to retrieve the user country and then set the corresponding timezone.

Another way is to get the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time using [JavaScript getTimezoneOffset() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) :

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

But it's easier to let the user setup its timezone manually.

Comment: I added this for the user '<g:timeZoneSelect name="myTimeZone" value="${tz}" />', but when tried to set the value to for example "Canada/Central", the default selection doesn't change.

Comment: The tag only create a dropdown list with all timezones but you have to store the value somewhere to reuse it later (in the session or in the DB if you have users account).